# Power BI Office 365 - Forecasting - Don't see dot and Analysis tab on the right side

Tags: powerview, powerbi

I have created a single line chart power view report sheet and uploaded to Office 365 Power BI app.

Then I have enabled HTML5 view, but I am not getting 'dot' for forecasting and not even analysis tab on the right hand side tab with filters.
[image]

Is there anything I am missing here?

I have followed all the steps mentioned on below link.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25531.getting-started-with-forecasting-and-hindcasting-in-power-view.aspx

Can anyone please help me?

Thank you,

Mittal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Power BI forecasting feature is currently disabled, pending a bug fix. See this post:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbi/archive/2014/12/10/power-bi-service-announcement-power-view-forecasting-offline-for-maintenance.aspx